# Profile pic not displayed in civimail

Tags: civimail, tokens

As per the requirement I'm trying to get the token values of the custom fields like name, date of birth,country, profile pic etc in the civimail .But when the email is sent.The profile picture is not displayed. Since I'm working on matrimonial site. It's mandatory to get the image in the email.Please help me on this. - Yes I want profile picture to be displayed in the email like all other values. I am getting surname,date of birth and Firstname but not profile pic.I am using tokens for custom fields.

Civicrm version- 7.x-4.7.9
I'm using Drupal 7.

The email output is as follows:
Singh
1969-04-04
Puneeth,
<>profile pic is not displayed.

### Html Source of email( I am using Mailtrap)

Singh

1969-04-04

Puneeth

Comment: Please update this question with details as to what CMS you are using and what versions of both CMS and CiviCRM.

Comment: Please update this question with the URL of the image that is getting embedded in the email.

Comment: Thanks. Based on the details you provided, it does not appear as the image is properly getting added to the email in its html.  Perhaps you can provide the source view of the email you are defining.  Click the source button in the email WYSIWYG editor and copy the content to your question.

Comment: I am using mailtrap for checking test emails, Content is as follows.<p>Singh</p>

<p>1969-04-04</p>

<p>
              <a href='/drupal_KC/civicrm/file?reset=1&amp;id=10&amp;eid=253' class='crm-image-popup' title='a.png'>
                <i class='crm-i fa-file-image-o'></i>
              </a></p>

<p>Puneeth</p>

Comment: Thanks for your quick reply. please suggest how I can get the image in email. I also tried including profile pic token within <img src> in the source while sending the email. But still I'm not getting the image

Answer (score 1):

Based on the content you provided, the problem I see is the src is missing from the image tag.  Be sure the URL you use is fully formed including the domain, ala, `src='http://mysite.com/.....'`     (Well, actually, you don't have a img tag in there.... I think you meant for the `i` tag to be the image??)

The href you have on the anchor tag has this problem, with the URL not including the actual URL.

Once you get the src set on the image, and if it's still not working, post the HTML from that source view.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I'm using tokens for the email, So I am including the token of the image custom field. in the sender email template. The same way I have included for all html elements. But only Image field(profile pic) is not appearing in the email.please suggest

Comment: Please provide the source of the email you are trying to send.

Comment: This is Source:<p>Surname:{contact.custom_150}</p>

<p>DOB:{contact.custom_152}</p>

<p>Firstname:&nbsp;{contact.custom_149}</p>

<p>profile pic:{contact.custom_173}</p>

Comment: Okay, cool. I think we are getting close! Can you provide me with a sample of the content of a `contact.custom_173` field.  I am assuming this custom field is a link field, correct?

Comment: Yes, contact.custom_173 is a image field. In email I'm getting the output this way:Surname:Singh

DOB:06/16/1983 12:00AM

Firstname: Puneeth

profile pic:       without image. Thanks for your quick reply

Comment: Well, there really isn't an image field in CiviCRM.  You probably are storing this as either a file field or a link field.  Do you know which it is?  And can you provide me with a sample of the content of the stored field?

Comment: Yes, I am storing it as a file field and used civicrm webform integration with drupal webforms. I am using a sample image https://pixabay.com/en/blank-profile-picture-mystery-man-973460/ saved and uploded in registration form .Thanks

Comment: So, just to verify, when you view a contact in CiviCRM, the file does show up there, correct?  Assuming it does, I think in your email source you need to code the image as `<img src="{contact.custom_173}" />`

Comment: Yes profile pic is appeared in civicrm profile  page. I tried<img src="{contact.custom_173}" /> this way but I'm not getting actual image in the email .Thanks

Comment: Hmmm, what is the html content in the email?  Can you view the source of the email and copy/paste the html?

Comment: This is the source: <p>Surname:{contact.custom_150}</p>

<p>DOB:{contact.custom_152}</p>

<p>Firstname:&nbsp;{contact.custom_149}</p>

<p>profile pic:<img src="{contact.custom_173}" /></p>

Comment: My bad. I meant the html source from the email that was sent and rec'd.  (ie, the html source content of the email that was received) and is not showing the image.

Comment: <p>Surname:Singh</p>

<p>DOB:06/16/1983 12:00AM</p>

<p>Firstname:&nbsp;Puneeth</p>

<p>profile pic:<img src="
              <a href='/drupal_KC/civicrm/file?reset=1&amp;id=10&amp;eid=253' class='crm-image-popup' title='m.png'>
                <i class='crm-i fa-file-image-o'></i>
              </a>" /></p>

<p><a href="">View profile</a> <a href="">Interested</a> <a href="">decline</a></p>

Comment: Oh, wow, CiviCRM isn't very cooperative with this.  It's embedding a link to the file, rather than just the URL.  Frankly, I think the best approach is to create a custom token in php to render just the URL.  Otherwise, I would suggest your changing the field to a text field, and just include the URL to the image there, referencing it in the email.